# Included FXML does not fit parent correctly

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm including several `FXML`s in one main `FXML` view but the thing is when I change the height of the parent which is an `AnchorPane` the included view height doesn't change and I didn't find anything in the doc regarding the size of included `FXML`. Any idea anyone?

```
<AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" SplitPane.resizableWithParent="false">
    <children>
        <fx:include fx:id="child" source="child.fxml" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: The layout will be performed by whatever container you place the root elements of the included FXMLs in (the `AnchorPane` in your case), according to constraints specified by those root elements (for an `AnchorPane` these would be things like the `leftAnchor`, `topAnchor`, etc). Please show some code showing what you are doing.

Comment: I know that, but for the included FXML in Scene Builder it doesn't show leftAnchor, topAnchor or whatever

Comment: It doesn't matter how you generate the FXML, it is going to be processed in the same way. So if you don't set those, then you won't get the results you want. (I don't use SceneBuilder much; I wasn't even aware you could do an `fx:include` in SceneBuilder...)

Comment: I did add then manually in the FXML code but it didn't change anything

Comment: Please post some code. You're asking people to help diagnose a problem they can't see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `AnchorPane` will attempt to resize its children based on the constraints you set on those child nodes. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html):

> The application sets anchor constraints on each child to configure the
>   anchors on one or more sides. If a child is anchored on opposite sides
>   (and is resizable), the anchor pane will resize it to maintain both
>   offsets, otherwise the anchor pane will resize it to its preferred
>   size. If in the former case (anchored on opposite sides) and the child
>   is not resizable, then only the top/left anchor will be honored.

In the code you posted, you haven't set any constraints on the child node, so it will just be sized to its preferred size.

For example, if you wanted the child to stretch to fill the entire `AnchorPane`, then you would do

```
<AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" SplitPane.resizableWithParent="false">
    <children>
        <fx:include fx:id="child" source="child.fxml" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0"
             AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"
             AnchorPane.buttonAnchor="0.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Note that this also assumes that whatever node is generated by `child.fxml` is allowed to grow to the size of the `AnchorPane` (e.g. it's `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` properties have appropriate values), and that the `AnchorPane` also grows when the window is resized, etc. You might also want to consider whether or not an `AnchorPane` is the best choice, or if [some other layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) might work better.

In short, there is nothing special about using an `<fx:include>` in terms of layout: it behaves just like any other scene graph hierarchy.